# Facing Late Initiliazation Error while initializing VideoPlayer

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking to play video in a screen using VideoPlayer. The video needs to be fetched from an API. Here is how my initState looks:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCandidateProfileVideo();
  }
```

I have the following two late variables in my stateful widget class and a global variable:

```
late VideoPlayerController _controller;
late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
String videoUrl = "";
```

getCandidateProfileVideo() is implemented as follows:

```
getCandidateProfileVideo() async {
  // await call to get video from REST API, and store the response in the variable videoUrl

  _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
        videoUrl,
      );
      _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
      _controller.setLooping(true);
      _controller.setVolume(1.0);
}
```

**Problem**

When I try to load the screen, I am getting the following issue: **LateInitializationError: Field '_initializeVideoPlayerFuture@75490850' has not been initialized.**

**Request**

What is wrong in my code that is causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `late` keyword when you are initializing an object in asynchronous function. You are initializing the video player object in getCandidateProfileView() which is asynchronous. By the time, the first frame is rendered by flutter, the video_player variable won't be initialized. That's why it throws `late initialization error`. To solve this, you can make your video_player variable of Nullable type.

```
VideoPlayerController? _controller;
Future<void>? _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
String videoUrl = "";
```

and wherever you use your VideoPlayerController `_controller` make sure to use `?.` or "!." nullable operators.

For ex:

```
_controller!.play() // you can use any function you want
```

For more information you can read about [dart's sound null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Just a Person's answer: 
If you want to keep using your `async` function you can consider using `FutureBuilder` widget which will call for your `async` function you put in it's `future` property and update `snapshot` when function returns some value
**Example:**

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: yourAsyncFunction(), 
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return snapshot.data;
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
)
```

For more information about `FutureBuilder` see [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Yes,I've already been using FutureBuilder for my VideoPlayer.